# Strange artifacts when using gl_FragCoord to access texels

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

I ran into a problem with using `gl_FragCoord` variable to access texels. The problem can be illustrated by following example:

First I render a textured quad into texture of size `(W, H)` where `W` and `H` are viewport width and height correspondingly. Then I draw another quad with lower left corner in `(0, 0)` and upper right corner in `(W, H)` (so that it effectively takes whole viewport) which is textured with this texture. Let's call it quad **A**. Then I draw another quad (let's call it quad **B**) on top of it, with lower left corner in `(0, H1)` and upper right in `(W, H)` and also use the same texture for it. The whole scene can be illustrated by this picture:

[image: scene]

As you can see, the bottom part of the first quad lays in quad **A** and a top part in quad **B**. Thus when I experiment with fragment shader for quad **B** I can see whether the top part of the quad matches the bottom part.

Now to the problem:

When in fragment shader for quad **B** I use

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, v_texCoord);
```

*(`v_texCoord` is (0, 0) for lower left corner and (1, 1) for upper right)*

to determine fragment color, everything is fine. Top and bottom parts of the first quad perfectly match each other:

[image: good]

However, when I change this line to:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution);
```

*(where u_resolution is a `vec2(W, H)`)*

the top and bottom parts of the quad doesn't match anymore. If I render that quad close to right edge of the screen I get following artifacts:

[image: artifacts right]

and if I draw it close to the left side artifacts looks like this:

[image: artifacts left]

Could anyone please explain what are the possible causes for such artifacts? Apparently I am missing some fundamental understanding of how texturing works, since in my mind `texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, v_texCoord)` should be completely equivalent to `texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution);` in my case.

*P.S. Obviously, for quad **A** I always use `gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_backgroundTexture, v_texCoord)` in fragment shader.*

Comment: Is `u_backgroundTexture` perhaps a texture you're rendering to?

Comment: Yes, it is the identifier of the texture to which I rendered first quad

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. I asked if that was the texture you're rendering to. That is, are you trying to render to a texture you're reading from simultaneously.

Comment: No, I only reading from this texture and render on screen. So the sequence looks like this: render first (small) quad into texture `u_backgroundTexture`, then render quad A on screen, then render quad B on screen. So both quads A and B only read values from this texture via `texture2D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root-cause of this weird discrepancy.

I use Cocos2d framework which builds projection matrix from the current camera settings. As it turned out, projection matrix built by Cocos2d has some precision loss. Thus, after vertices of quads **A** and **B** multiplied by projection matrix, the result vertices don't hit exact points `(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1)` in NDC as I would expect. The actual NDC of the points look more like `(-1.00164..., -1.00164...)` etc. This causes texture on quad **A** to be just a little bit stretched which is why it doesn't match texture on quad **B**.

To "fix" for this issue I changed coordinates of quads **A** and **B** to NDC and removed multiplication by Cocos2d's projection matrix from vertex shader.